# Efficiency of my Workout

Tags: cardio, burn-fat

I am currently working out 4 days a week. 3 of them I do weights focusing on different areas plus a bit of Cardio to warm up (20-30 mins running, spinning bike or X-trainer when I workout upper body, and 10 mins of those mentioned plus 10 mins of static row when I train legs).
The 4th day I used to swim and run for an hour or so. 
However,  I am trying to burn some fat from my belly and under triceps. I want to use this 4th day to focus on that purpose. I thought, in order to do that, do a longer workout, consisting on:

1) A 'long', around 45-60 mins,  moderate (60%-80% of MHR)  initial part, like running, cycle, X-trainer etc. That part would be after fasting to stimulate the difficult-to-burn fat.
2) A break of 10-20 mins, including a sugar intake (such as a fruit or shake)
3) 20-30 mins of a High Intensity Circuit to stimulate my metabolism for the rest of the day.

Can this be effective?

Am I at risk of start burning aminoacids?

I would be very happy to hear about other approaches to pursue my goal using that 4th day and any other feedback.

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: You cannot target fat loss, it happens gradually all over. And cardio isn’t going to do anything special for reaching that goal either. It will certainly burn some extra calories and help your cardiovascular endurance, but the only thing that gets rid of fat is a caloric deficit.

Comment: Thanks! I had read that there are strategies in order to target the burnage of fat instead of sugar (the purpose of fasting). As well, I had read, too, that HIIT makes your metabolism  faster for the rest of the day. Of course, the main goal is to burn the calories to get a caloric deficit, but I thought there are ways to target the usage of fat during the workout.

Comment: Excess Post-Exercise Oxygen Consumption (EPOC) is a factor that can help, it just seems like your example goes beyond what would be beneficial. It's hard to say whether it's too much in the sense that it's detrimental, but unless you're training for a specific athletic goal it just seems senseless to spend 1.5 hours on cardio exclusively to burn more calories when you could just as easily eat a 200-400 less calories and accomplish the same thing. Also, if you are burning more fat than carbs in an exercise session, your body will just compensate for it later. So it just goes back to calories.

Comment: With regards to your question, consider this video -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ir83IWRVTOw

Comment: Thanks very much for the feedback! I really appreciate your pieces of advice. The video is really enlightening!